# OpenLayers 3: Remove event listener

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In [Openlayers 3](http://openlayers.org/) how to remove a event listener attached like this:

```
var a = map.on("pointerdrag",function (e) {
             // event handler
});

var b = map.on("pointerdrag",function (e) {
             // event handler
});
```

How do I remove only listner `a` and keep `b` active?

Answer (score 11):

Ah its pretty simple! Its in the [API Docs](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.Map.html#unByKey): `unByKey`, but very counter-intuitive name for an off function.

So to remove the event listener `a`:

```
map.unByKey(a);
```

Will remove `a` listener but keep the `b` on.

Note: this will work across any object in Open Layers 3 that emits an event. like Layers, Interactions etc..

Comment: Note you can also use `.un`, if you are using a named function.
`function onPointerDragOne() {/*do stuf*/}`
`function onPointerDragTwo() {/*do stuf*/}`
`map.on("pointerdrag", onPointerDragOne);`
`map.on("pointerdrag", onPointerDragTwo);`
`map.un("pointerdrag", onPointerDragOne);`
`// Only onPointerDragTwo will run`

Answer (score 1):

I was just wondering the same thing, seems like `off` would be the appropriate method to remove an event listener.  You can also call this directly in the event callback:

```
map.on("pointerdrag", function (e) {
    map.unByKey(e);
});
```

This should remove only the this specific event.

Comment: Why I'll do such thing?